# Rest Design for a task queue

Tags: rest

I'm designing a task queue rest interface and wondering about a best practice.

One action is to accept the "next" task in the queue.

By accepting the job only the first worker will get the job.

The worker won't know the task or the task id until accepting the job.

Now I'm thinking I can't use a GET because it's not idempotent. If calling nextTask two times you get two different jobs. So I guess it should be a POST.

POST //rest/taskqueue?action=acceptTask

Or am I looking at it the wrong way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically:

- GET - Reads data without modifying a resource (idempotent). You can do as many GETs as you want, it will never modify the resource.
- PUT - Puts data explicitly in a resource (not idempotent)
- POST - Appends data in a resource (not idempotent)
- DELETE - Removes data from a resource (not idempotent)

This is how I would do it.

Enqueue a new task:

```
--> POST http://api.crazyjoes.com/v1/tasks/
--> {"data":{"lulcat":true}}
<-- 202 Accepted
```

Enqueue a new task with a specific ID:

```
--> PUT http://api.crazyjoes.com/v1/tasks/393ee7f6-c44a-4b34-86ac-92c9f31a4bc6/
--> {"data":{"lulcat":true}}
<-- 202 Accepted
```

Retrieve the oldest task:

```
--> GET http://api.crazyjoes.com/v1/tasks/oldest/
<-- 200 OK
<-- {"id":123,"data":{"lulcat":true}}
```

If the queue is empty:

```
--> GET http://api.crazyjoes.com/v1/tasks/oldest/
<-- 204 No Content
```

Dequeue a specific task:

```
--> DELETE http://api.crazyjoes.com/v1/tasks/123/
<-- 200 OK
<-- {"id":123,"data":{"lulcat":true}}
```

If the task has already been handled...

```
--> DELETE http://api.crazyjoes.com/v1/tasks/123/
<-- 410 Gone
```

If you want to dequeue the oldest item directly...

```
--> DELETE http://api.crazyjoes.com/v1/tasks/oldest/
<-- 200 OK
<-- {"id":123,"data":{"lulcat":true}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer this makes sense. Actually I was thinking of not immediately deleting the task from the queue but to just change the status from NEW to ACCEPTED and then to COMPLETED once it's done. That way I can track the tasks that were accepted but never completed to put them back on the queue if needed. Maybe I can just send 409 conflict instead of 410 Gone in that case. Or like you suggested have another table for the ACCEPTED/PENDING/COMPLETED jobs and send the 410.

Comment: Hmm, this design doesn't seem like it addresses the OP's requirement that "By accepting the job only the first worker will get the job".  Two workers could independently grab the oldest task, since this design doesn't dequeue the task or mark it as claimed when fetching the oldest task.  A suggestion:

    -->POST http://api.crazyjoes.com/v1/task_distributor
    <--200 OK

returns and dequeues (or marks as "claimed") the oldest task.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

`/tasks` and `/tasks/{taskId}` are the usual collection of all tasks and an individual task, respectively.

`/tasksqueue` is the tasks on the queue, while `/tasksqueue/top` is the top of the queue, and only supports a GET. Let's assume that all tasks have a unique id.

Then issue `GET /tasksqueue/top` to get the id of the task at the top of the queue, and issue a `DELETE /tasksqueue/{taskId}` to attempt to pop it off the queue.

If it fails, i.e. returns a non-20x, it means someone else popped the queue between your calls.

If it succeeds, it will return the task in its body and you can do what you want with it, knowing you've successfully popped it. Or since you know its id, you can get the task info from `/tasks/{taskId}`.

It shouldn't succeed more than once.

And you can issue `DELETE /tasksqueue/{taskId}` multiple times with the same overall effect on the system as just one of them, hence `DELETE` is acting idempotently as it should. (The fact that all, or all but the first, `DELETE` calls return a non-20x doesn't alter that fact.)

Comment: If it's really important that two different workers will not get the same task this is a good way. However there is a risk that when the delete is done (ie an item is popped) it is not actually completed for some reason.

A variation would be to send the entire item on get and then confirm its completion with a delete. This would however risk that two workers get the same item and then duplicate work.

Guess you'd choose depending on how bad duplicated work is and how bad a lost item is in your application. Unless there is a way to solve both cases?

Answer (score 0):

POST is the "append" verb, and also the "data processing" verb per the HTTP spec. So, conceptually, you're appending a task to a task list for processing. POST is just right.

Another reason GET isn't right is because GET isn't supposed to make changes to the resource. But the incoming request *is* going to make changes... it will add one item.

I would leave off the "action=acceptTask". In REST, the HTTP verb specifies your intent, and the URI specifies the target. So what you're doing is appending a new task to the queue... the "action" parameter doesn't add anything.

Generally, if you want to provide additional information to the request, you can add parameters to provide modifiers about what to do. But the other convention is to more or less cheat and put then intention at the end of the URI and treat it as a sub-resource (that is, instead of a parameter). e.g.:

```
ht_p://.../taskqueue/fold
ht_p://.../taskqueue/roll
ht_p://.../taskqueue/rattle
(hm. not sure how many things you can actually do with a queue...)
```

However, you should never duplicate the HTTP verbs... that's a misuse of the underlying protocol and a no-no in REST:

```
ht_p://.../taskqueue/get
ht_p://.../taskqueue/update
ht_p://.../taskqueue/delete
...ack!
```